# C# WPF Prism Модули

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть Shell с одним регионом (content), допустим модуль SharedServicesModule использует етот регион при старте и регистрироет / логинит кого - небудь. Как теперь перейти из SharedServicesModule в UIModule? Тоесть показать например ShoppingView в content? И правильно ли я проектирую?

Comment: `И правильно ли я проектирую` - это только вам известно. Prism дает много свободы как и что делать, потому не думайте, что Prism вам подскажет как вам надо спроектировать ваше приложение - вам по прежнему надо самому заботиться о архитектуре приложения.

Comment: Вам нужно загрузить этот модуль для начала. Затем можете навигироваться как хотите